# How to change all elements in the array to 1 or zero if odd or even

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array and I need to change the values to 0 if odd, 1 if even. How can I do that?

```
arr  = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
```

Comment: `(arr + 1) % 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=modulo#binary-arithmetic-operations) is useful here:

```py
arr % 2
```

This results in `1` everywhere you have an odd number (because there's a remainder of 1 under integer division by 2), which is the opposite of what you want.

To flip it, substract it from 1:

```py
1 - arr % 2
```

On your data, this gives:

```py
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Note that this doesn't actually *change* your input data, which is what you asked for. You could achieve that by overwriting `arr` with this result.

Comment: `1 - (arr & 1)` to avoid modulo.